# Bind Configuration Array value to Class Instance

Tags: .net-core, configuration

I have an in-memory collection as below. I am trying to bind it  to a class object. But am getting only null value.

```
 var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:restrictedToMinimumLevel", "Error" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name", "Console" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:formatter", "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:path", "c:\\log.json" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:restrictedToMinimumLevel", "Verbose" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:rollingInterval", "Day" },
        { "Serilog:WriteTo:1:Name", "File" },
      };
```

I add the above collection  it into my configuration object.

```
builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(data);
```

I try to assign these values into a class object.

```
var x = builder.Configuration.GetValue<Rootobject>("Serilog");
```

My class is structured as below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Serilog Serilog { get; set; }
}

public class Serilog
{
    public Writeto[] WriteTo { get; set; }
}



public class Writeto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Args Args { get; set; }
}

public class Args
{         
    public string path { get; set; }         
    public string formatter { get; set; }
    public string restrictedToMinimumLevel { get; set; }         
    public bool rollingInterval{ get; set; }
}
```

The Variable  'X' is always null. could someone helpme in letting me know the issue.